# MVC Date Validation Fails on return to page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model property setup as below

```
[DisplayName("Target Date")]
[DateValidInFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Date (dd/mm/yyyy)")]
public string TargetDate { get; set; }
```

On the UI the date validation works fine when the page is posted but when control returns to the browser the field is marked with the error message.  I can delete the value and re-enter it and it works fine.  It only fails for dates in the future.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `asp.net-mvc` but your datatype shouldn't be `DateTime` instead of `string`? And remember, `/` format specifier has a special meaning as _replace me current culture date separator_.

Comment: Yes, You gave statement about what is happening. What is your requirement here ?

Comment: What is the culture on the server (is a date in the format `dd/MM/yyyy` valid)? And what is `[DateValidInFormat]`? (its not an inbuilt validation attribute so how could we know what it does)